# Why are we repeating the Torah portion this week?

Tags: parsha-torah-portion, simchat-torah

Wasn't last week Parshat Vezot Hab'rachah?
But we are now repeating it!

Am I off a portion or are we actually repeating it?

Comment: What may be confusing you is the fact that *Vezot Habracha* is always read in the middle of the week (except in Israel when Simchat Torah can occur on Shabbat.) Thus, technically, **two** parshiot occur in the same week - Vezot and Breishit. However, it's hardly ever "announced" that way, as most places (shuls, bulletins, announcements, etc.) generally refer to the week by the Shabbat parsha, so you may see in announcements "Wednesday of parshat Breishit" before Simchat Torah has occurred somewhere in the middle of that week.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the first day of Rosh Hashanah falls out on Monday or Tuesday (as it did this year):

- Nitzavim alone is read on the Shabbos before Rosh Hashanah.
- Vayeilech is read between Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur.
- Haazinu is read between Yom Kippur and Sukkos.
- A special reading, taken from Parshas Ki Sisa, is read on Shabbos Chol Hamoed.
- Vezos Habracha is read on Simchas Torah.
- Bereishis is read on the Shabbos following Sukkos, and the usual schedule resumes from there.

If the first day of Rosh Hashanah falls out on Thursday:

- Nitzavim and Vayeilech are read together on the Shabbos before Rosh Hashanah.
- Haazinu is read between Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur.
- There is no Shabbos between Yom Kippur and Sukkos in such years.
- A special reading, taken from Parshas Ki Sisa, is read on Shabbos Chol Hamoed.
- Vezos Habracha is read on Simchas Torah.
- Bereishis is read on the Shabbos following Sukkos, and the usual schedule resumes from there.

If the first day of Rosh Hashanah falls out on Shabbos:

- Nitzavim and Vayeilech are read together on the Shabbos before Rosh Hashanah.
- Haazinu is read between Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur.
- There is no Shabbos between Yom Kippur and Sukkos in such years.
- A special reading, taken from Parshas Emor, is read on the first day of Sukkos, which will be a Shabbos.
- Outside Eretz Yisrael: A special reading, taken from Parshas Re’eh, is read on the first day of Shmini Atzeres, which will also be a Shabbos. The following day will be Simchas Torah, in which Vezos Habracha is read.
- Inside Eretz Yisrael: Shmini Atzeres is only one day, a Shabbos, on which Simchas Torah is celebrated and Vezos Habracha is read.
- Bereishis is read on the Shabbos following Sukkos, and the usual schedule resumes from there.

Not sure where you lost track, but this should cover all the bases where you might have gotten off schedule. Some of the rules described above are discussed in Megillah 31a and 31b, and all are codified by the Shulchan Aruch in OC 428:4, 659:1, 663:3, 668:2, and 669:1.

Comment: Possible reasons why OP might have been confused: they saw a "parasha of the week" sign that said VHB two weeks in a row, they heard VHB lained during the week or shabbos mincha two weeks in a tow, etc. Perhaps elaborate a bit on the special reading for CH"M sukkos and the effect on the laining during the week.

Comment: @Daniel I’m not sure what more there is to elaborate upon there.